# setInterval(function() { window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight); }, 2000); the page keep scrolling down... please how do I stop this action?

Tags: javascript, html

I inserted this variables in my chrome browser:

```
setInterval(function() { window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight); }, 2000);
```

The webpage have been scrolling down, I have used `return` action system.exit but its not stopping...

Please how do I stop this action, the page keep scrolling down and hanging.

Comment: Refresh the page.

Comment: Just remove the code? What is the desired effect? To change the scroll position only once on page load? Also, __never__ copy-paste some arbitrary code to your page if you don't fully understand it.

Answer (score 1):

setInterval is a function that EVERY 2000ms (2nd argument) executes the action you wrote (1st argument = scroll down in your case). [See this link for setInterval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

This behaviour is completely normal with setInterval.

Thus, what action would you perform?

Probably in your case just window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight) should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run the code and stop it after a while you should store the interval id returned by the function:

```
const scroll = setInterval(function() { 
  window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight); 
 }, 2000);
```

So you can cancel it at any time:

```
clearInterval(scroll);
```

Answer (score 1):

The setInterval function returns an identifier (ID). In the event that this ID is lost, it is possible to clear all intervals using a brute force approach.

If you want to stop all interval, you can use this function.

```
function clearAllIntervals() {
    for (var i = 1; i < 99999; i++) {
        // Attempt to clear intervals using a brute force approach
        window.clearInterval(i);
    }
}
```

**DISCLAIMER:** This method should be used cautiously and is not recommended as a standard practice. It assumes consecutive IDs starting from 1, and there are more controlled ways to manage intervals.

Comment: Hello, please don't post code only and add an explantation as to why you think that this is the optimal solution. People are supposed to learn from your answer, which might not occur if they just copy paste code without knowing why it should be used.

Comment: @Destroy666 Thank you for your answer. I'm adding an explanation immediately.